# How to code a template that jumps a branch and redirects to one specific page in wagtail?

Tags: wagtail

Tree structure is as follows, How would I code a template that jumps from "section 1" to "discussion a" for all sections?

I am using topic 1,2...etc as organization pages and for navigation in my discussion pages. I think this can be done using page.get_parent to jump topics and page.get_siblings to jump discussions.

Can wagtail templates jump to specific models? Perhaps I can have a unique model just for discussion a and have section 1,2...etc auto jump to corresponding discussion in its branch?

```
Section 1
    topic 1
        discussion a: “why are tree’s blue?”
        discussion b
    topic 2
Section 2
    topic 1
        discussion a “why are tree’s yellow?”
```

I tried page.get_decendents but that just list everything below the tree branch. I was thinking of using snippets but any topic can have many discussions and any section can have many topics. I chosen this approach as it would be automatic.

Comment: I am afraid it isn't clear what "jumps" means. 

Is the diagram above your current page tree? And are you trying to create a visible menu that only displays the section and discussion pages but not the topic pages? If so, why are you using topic pages rather than having topic tags? https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#id1

Answer (score 0):

You would do this if you have a separate model for the discussion pages, using the `type` function on the page queryset. See [Wagtail Page queryset documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.query.PageQuerySet.type)

If your models are structured like this:

```
class DiscussionPage(Page):
    # ...

class SectionPage(Page):
    # ...
```

Then you could have a function that can get the first discussion descendant like this:

```
class DiscussionPage(Page):
    # ...

class SectionPage(Page):
    # ...
    def get_first_discussion_page(self):
        return self.get_descendants().type(DiscussionPage).specific().first()
```

The only caveat is that `type` only accepts a class as an argument so that it has to be defined before using it.

In your template you could then call `get_first_discussion_page` as needed.